Cheese is broken in 24.04
Recently when trying to run Cheese, my whole display goes blank, and I can't even do REISUB, or get to an alternate terminal, and then I have to hard reboot my system.
I'm using Ubuntu MATE, 24.04 and Cheese has been working for a while, but now it fails.
Then I downloaded the source code from the Gitlab repo, acquired listed dependencies, and tried compiling, it.
when I ran ~/cheese$ meson setup build the same thing happened.
I'd prefer to continue using Cheese, if I can get some assistance in fixing it.
The last thing in the meson log is:
Running command: /usr/bin/gst-inspect-1.0 camerabin

Full text meson log here

Check if it helps if you use snap instead. Use the command sudo apt remove cheese followed by sudo snap install cheese

You might want to test if your need to switch back to X11 rather than Wayland -- some applications do not play nice with Wayland.
To turn off Wayland:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf     
    #.Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
    WaylandEnable=false    ← turns off Wayland, turns on X11

